# Сколько потоков запускает parallelStream

Tags: java, потоки-данных, parallelstream

Имеется массив из `N` элементов.

Сколько потоков запускает на выполнение `arr.parallelStream()`, если количество ядер - 4 (пусть будет `M`) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paralell stream использует `ForkJoinPool`, количество потоков в котором обычно равно `Число ядер - 1` (Однако может быть изменено через аргумент запуска JVM) а также главный поток. И в итоге количество потоков равно: `ForkJoinPool.getCommonPoolParallelism() + 1`.